# elixir how to send data to websockets repeatedly

Tags: elixir

I have a process that reads a file, for this test it reads a line every second

I want all connected websockets to receive the same line

e.g;

if user 1 connects he receives line 1, after a second line 2.. after a second line 3.. line 4.. and so on

if user 2 connects after 3 seconds he receives line 3, a second after he and receives line 4 and so on..

how do I implement this ? should I use cowboy v1 or v2 ?

this is the code for the process that read from file using PubSub

```
defp stream_from_file(fpath, bytes) do
    File.stream!(fpath, [], bytes)
    |> Enum.each(fn chunk ->
      PubSub.publish(:topic1, {:topic1_data, chunk})
      :timer.sleep(1_000)
    end)
    stream_from_file(fpath, bytes)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Phoenix. In that case you can call broadcast on your Endpoint from wherever. So you could replace Your PubSub.publish line with:

```
MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast("room1", "topic1", %{topic_data: chunk})
```

Such message will be sent to all users that joined room1 channel with "topic1" event, so on client side you would receive it with:

```
let channel = socket.channel("room1", {})
channel.join()
  .receive("topic1", body => { console.log(body.topic_data) })
```

Comment: using [{:plug, "~> 1.0"}, {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}, {:pubsub, "~> 0.0.2"}], low level to better understand whats going on